# Fetch Label Content of Custom Cell

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a custom cell (with 5 labels) which populates my custom UITableView.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //--> Need to get content of each label within the custom cell
}
```

Appreciate the help
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it different ways

**Best way is using Tags**

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

  //get the labels using Tag from cell
  UILabel *label = ([[cell.contentView viewWithTag:yourTag] isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])?(UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:yourTag]:nil;


}
```

**Second Way is using subview looping.**

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

  for(id subView in [cell.contentView subView])
  {

     if([subViews isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
     {
       UILabel *label = (UILabel *)subViews;
     }
 }

}
```

**Custom Cell class Example:**

```
UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init]
myLabel.tag = 1;
[self.contentView addSubView:myLabel];
```

Comment: If it's a custom cell, I think the easiest way is to have IBOutlets to each label, then you can get the value with cell.label1.text, cell.label2.text, etc.

Comment: nope.. use [self.contentView addSubView:myLabel];  I have edited the answer,,, please see the "Custom Cell class Example" section in my answer

Comment: What do you mean by "nope"? I'm offering my opinion as an alternative way to do this. You're entitled to your opinion, and I'm entitled to mine.

Comment: ha ha. ..let him to decide dude,, he can use whatever he need... I appreciate your suggestion too :)